# What is the probability that a cheque processed by this bank will be returned due to insufficient funds?

Tags: probability, statistics

A bank has studied its chequing accounts and found that $92\%$ of all chequing accounts have been open for at least one year, the remaining percentage of chequing accounts have been open for less than a year. The bank also determined that for all chequing accounts that have been open for less than one year, the percentage of cheques returned due to insufficient funds is $5\%$. For chequing accounts that have been open for at least one year, only $1\%$ of cheques were returned due to insufficient funds.

(a) What is the probability that a cheque processed by this bank will be returned due to insufficient funds?

(b) If a cheque is returned due to insufficient funds, what is the probability that it came from a bank account that has been open for more than one year?

Here is what I have tried so far:

$a> (0.05/0.08)*(0.01/0.92)$

$b> 1-(0.05/0.08)$

Not exactly sure how to approach this question correctly..

Regards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- Suppose there were $10,000$ accounts in total.
- How many would have been open less than a year?

  - How many would have been open less than a year and would have a cheque returned due to insufficient funds?
- How many would have been open more than a year?

  - How many would have been open more than a year and would have a cheque returned due to insufficient funds?
- How many accounts in total would have a cheque returned due to insufficient funds?

  - What proportion of the initial $10,000$ accounts would have a cheque returned due to insufficient funds?
  - What proportion of accounts having a cheque returned due to insufficient funds were accounts open more than a year?

Comment: Got the first part. Kinda stuck on (b). I'm thinking it's 0.92 (i.e. proportion of accounts open more than a year)

Comment: Nevermind, makes sense. Thank you! :)